# Prove Fib(n) is closest integer to golden ratio

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers

Does anyone know why it's suggested this proof use $\psi = (1 - \sqrt 5)/2$?  I'm a bit lost here.  Guidance appreciated.

[PROOF Link](https://codology.net/post/sicp-solution-exercise-1-13/)

[image: Start of Proof]

Comment: $|\psi|<1$ so $\psi^n\to0$;  note that $\psi=-1/\varphi$

Comment: @J. w. tanner Thanks, but I'm still confused...

Comment: Can you articulate exactly which part you’re confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Is it clear for you why $Fib(n)=(\phi^n-\psi^n)/\sqrt{5}$? If not, try here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence#Fibonacci_sequence

When that's done, you should apply Tanner's hint to see that: $$\mid\psi\mid<1 \implies \mid Fib(n)-\phi^n/\sqrt{5}\mid=\mid\psi\mid^n/\sqrt{5} < 1, $$

Comment: No, I will read this and Binet's formula.  Thanks for the pointers.